# Codeigniter pagination in same page with search option

Tags: codeigniter

I has problem to implement CI pagination to my search page, however my query can populate search results when it was first loaded, when I clicked on the page 2 onwards, and again seach another keyword then its not search and page redirect to search page and second time when i search it works fine, can someone please give me an advise on what's wrong in  my code?
and please give me some exapmle.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem then i implement one logic that is i passed two parameter in url first is identifier and second is value

e.g. i want search then i will use

```
https://domain.com/name/search/mohit
```

e.g. for pagination

```
https://domain.com/name/page/2
```

in controller

```
function name(identify='',value=''){
}
```